# Cannot move out of `current` because it is borrowed while returning from recursion

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Let's consider my Storage struct which contains a vector of keys in u16:

```
pub struct Storage {
    ...
    pub root: Option<RefCell<Node>>,
}


pub struct Node {
    pub keys: RefCell<Vec<u16>>,
    pub children: RefCell<Vec<Node>>,
}
```

At some point during the recursion as the call iterating through the children of children and searching for the key provided,

```
pub fn search(&'a self, key: u16, current: Ref<'a, Node>) -> (usize, Ref<'a, Node>) {
    let keys = current.keys.borrow();
    for index in 0..keys.len() {
        if keys[index] == key && current.is_leaf() {
            return (index, current);
        }
    }
}
```

The recursion terminates by return statement. The function call is expected to return the index of the matching key and the current Node instance so that the caller can make some modifications. But, rustc is complaining about it:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `current` because it is borrowed
  --> src/index/btree.rs:87:36
   |
84 |             let keys = current.keys.borrow();
   |                        ------- borrow of `current` occurs here
...
87 |                     return (index, current);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^ move out of `current` occurs here
...
90 |         }
   |         - borrow might be used here, when `keys` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Ref<'_, Vec<u16>>`
```

I understand that the function borrows the keys at line 84 and so long as the "keys" reference is around, i.e. until they get dropped post method call, but my question is what is the idiomatic way to handle this in the algorithm? Especially without cloning the objects which sounds like a workaround to me?

Comment: You might be able to [get around this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.map). But really, read [too-many-linked-lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/second-iter.html), especially the [chapters on iterators](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/second-iter.html). It's about what you're doing, and why it's not such a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must be missing something important from your example. It doesn't compile as is.

Changing it to fix the most obvious issues, and switching from passing `Ref<'a, Node>` to just passing `&Node`, then it compiles for me:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

pub struct Node {
    pub keys: RefCell<Vec<u16>>,
    pub children: RefCell<Vec<Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn is_leaf(&self) -> bool {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub fn search(key: u16, current: &Node) -> Option<(usize, &Node)> {
    let keys = current.keys.borrow();
    for index in 0..keys.len() {
        if keys[index] == key && current.is_leaf() {
            return Some((index, current));
        }
    }
    None
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f0ae75422458645b6521ac3803f0411c

Comment: Thanks Michael. The reason why the method takes Refs as parameters is due to interior mutability of Node's owner, that is Storage. I updated my code snippet above. So, the search begins from the root node, which is a RefCell. Do you have any suggestions on a better idiomatic design?

Comment: @ErhanBagdemir In general, there is a very little reason to take `Ref`. You can always transform the `Ref` to `&` by `&*` (reborrowing) it.

Comment: @ErhanBagdemir can you create a minimal self contained example that demonstrates the issue? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) At the moment there are too many other errors in the code to be sure of what you're trying to do.